# How to get and write data in text file Like Database

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop a small program. I want to write and get data from a text file like if it were a database. I have some data ex:

```
User = abc,
Age = 12,
No = 154
```

I want to write that data in the text file and after I want so search data using `User`. I don't know how to that. Can anyone tell how to do this.

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./output.txt"));
    writer.write("your data here");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a small footprint database for this task, such as SQLite?

Comment: object serialization maybe ?

Comment: no i want add it on txt file.

Comment: Why not use an XML file?  It has the benefits of being a flat-file (which you want), and the ability to be queried like a database (which you want as well).

Comment: You need to parse it into memory, then write it back onto the disk. Write a separate function for each one - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87

Comment: @Makoto You're preaching to the wrong choir, I've had firsthand experience with these situations where databases/modern data storage techniques are too complicated/unnecessary for people who are content with simply storing everything unencrypted on a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I know why do you want this..?? Because as the request for read and write will Increase your code will reach the bottle neck. You want to perform heavy I/O operations for getting the lite data. Disk I/O is heaving is its own concurrent read restrictions. So I will not suggest you to use such approach for getting the lite data. You may put some heavy data like Images/ Videos/ Songs etc in files using some unique ID that will be a good approach but like this I will nor prefer you.. But at all you want to do this than go for property files which works on key and value. Put values token separated and split at the time of consumption.

Comment: thanks friend. i was used property file. that's good idea. thanks :D